# how to setup onClickListeners for each slide in a viewpager?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

The `ImageAdapter` Class

```
public class ImageAdapter extends PagerAdapter implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {
    Context context;
    private int[] GalImages = new int[] {//array storing all images used in the 'slideshow' in the main menu
            R.drawable.savedpageex,
            R.drawable.ic_cdi_icon,
            R.drawable.savedpageex,
            R.drawable.ic_cdi_icon
    };

    ImageAdapter(Context context){
        this.context=context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return GalImages.length;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == ((ImageView) object);
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
      //  int padding = context.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.abc_panel_menu_list_width);
        imageView.setPadding(1, 1, 1, 1);
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
        imageView.setImageResource(GalImages[position]);
        ((ViewPager) container).addView(imageView, 0);

        return imageView;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        ((ViewPager) container).removeView((ImageView) object);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        final int clickedImage = GalImages[position];
    }
}
```

In the MainActivity

```
ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.viewpager);

ImageAdapter adapter = new ImageAdapter(this);
wrappedAdapter = new InfinitePagerAdapter(adapter);
viewPager.setAdapter(wrappedAdapter);

viewPager.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});
```

Right now, the pictures show up and they loop, I do need help getting the pictures to 'slide' at set time intervals, but the main issue is with setting up onClickListeners for each 'page'. Any help/advice?

Comment: Have you tried to override the `public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)` method?

Comment: It isn't already overrided?

Answer (score 0):

You could add a switch statement inside of the onClickListener like this

```
switch(viewPager.getCurrentItem()){
    case 0:
       //stuff for first page
       break;
    case 1: 
       //stuff for second page
       break;
}
```

...... etc.

or add a state to the viewpager to describe which "page" it is showing
and using that information do different things in the onClickListener

Comment: I tried what you suggested and unfortunately it ultimately did not make a difference(currently it does nothing no matter what I click. I set up simple toast messages to pop up when each button is clicked, but nothing appears at the moment when a page is clicked.